# How to load multiple category id in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Hi i want to load multiple category id in magento, i used in this but it fetch only 1st category of subcategory not rest of category.

```
$category = $model->load(79,80,91);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
$categories = array(1,2,3);
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$categories));
foreach($category as $categorys) {
//or do Somthing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use collection instead of load

```
  $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addIdFilter(array(79,80,91))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active categories if you want
                ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'desc'); //sort by position
```

and then you can use loop throw

```
foreach($collection as $category) {
    echo $category->getName()
}
```

hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this,

```
$categories = array(10,13);
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$cats = $_category->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$categories));

foreach($cats as $cat) { 

    Zend_Debug::dump($cat);
    //or
    // do Somthing 
}
```